SQL select query that adds a new column name to output only (result values will be null)
For SQL SELECT queries, we often have requests to include a field name in the csv output which does not exist in the database.  (to match the format of another system\database, for example)
To handle this, I usually just edit the csv output file in Excel to add the extra column names as necessary.  But there must be a simple method to accomplish this directly in the SQL query?
I don't want to alter the database in any way, the new column name would only be used for the query output.  Also, there would not be any values for the result records- all results for this added field would be NULL.
Example: A database has TABLE1, with existing fields for Name, City, Phone.
Name     City         Phone
John     Princeton    333-444-5555
Paul     Denver       222-888-7777
Sarah    Detroit      987-654-3210

So I can query: select "Name", "City", "Phone" from TABLE1
But, is there a way to query so the results include a NewColumn name inserted, with null values for that field, so that output would look like this?
Name     City         NewColumn   Phone
John     Princeton                333-444-5555
Paul     Denver                   222-888-7777
Sarah    Detroit                  987-654-3210


select "Name", "City", null as NewColumn, "Phone" from TABLE1

Thank you for the suggestion, but it didn't work for me.  I should add that I'm running query on Advantage Database, and not SQL database.  I tested your suggestion but I get an error "Expected lexical element not found: identifier or expression".  This could be a limitation of the Advantage Database Architect program that I am using to run query.  Any other suggestions for syntax?

Code samples from http://www.jensendatasystems.com/ADSBook10/ strongly suggest that Advantage uses pretty standard SQL syntax. So sepupic's suggestion should work. Your sample query puts the fields in quotation marks, but that seems unusual. Try leaving out the quotation marks, so Select Name, City, null as NewColumn, Phone from TABLE1.

It does not work for me either way (with or without quotes for field names), this must be a limitation in the ARC program?  The full error I get in ARC program is "poQuery: Error 7200:  AQE Error:  State = 42000;   NativeError = 2115;  [iAnywhere Solutions][Advantage SQL Engine]Expected lexical element not found: identifier or expression -- Location of error in the SQL statement is: 32 [Parsing Expression (column 3 in the
SELECT clause)]"

I found a workaround, I was able to use this syntax: '' AS [NewColumn], (instead of  null as NewColumn).  thank you everyone for the suggestions.

Select Name, City, '' AS [NewColumn], Phone from TABLE1


Don't forget to accept the answer, if it solved your issue ;-)
